# Chaining Method Calls to a Mockito Mock Returns Null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, method-chaining

I have a following `@Component` with an injected object that makes a chain method call to get something, e.g.

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

  @Autowired
  public MyProducer producer;

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(…) throws IOException {
    String val = producer.getProducer().getSomeVal(/*parameters*/); // LINE (1)
  }

}
```

And my test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyInterceptor.class, MyProducer.class } )

public class MyInterceptorTest {

  private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  private MockRestSErviceServer mockServer;

  @Rule
  public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Mock
  public MyProducer producer;

  @InjectMocks
  private MyInterceptor interceptor;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    //MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this);
    producer = Mockito.mock(MyProducer.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    // adding interceptor to RestTemplate
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

    when(producer.getProducer().getSomeVal(null, null)).thenReturn("SomeValue");

  }

  @Test
  public void myTestMethod() {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo(/*some dummy URL*/)
      .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
      .andExcept(/*some header stuff omitted from MyInterceptor */)
      .andRespond(withSuccess(/*…*/));

    // This is going to trigger the Interceptor being invoked
    restTemplate.getForEntity("some dummy URL", String.class); // LINE (2)

    mockServer.verify();
  }
}
```

When the test executes LINE (2), and it invokes the interceptor, in LINE (1) I get a null pointer exception.

I was under the assumption that by enabling deep stubbing on a mock, I would be able to make a chain call and get an expected value, e.g. `producer.getProducer().getSomeVal()`, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Do you know how I can get this working as expected?

P.S. I have tried different variation of adding `MockitoAnnotation.initMocks()` and getting rid of `@Rule`, or just `@Autowired` `MyInterceptor` in the test class which in this causes `MyProducer` not to be mocked at all, but nothing seems to work.

Note, `MyProducer` cannot be modified as it is from another project.

Comment: Can you split the implementation of `intercept()` into two lines? The first is just `producer.getProducer()` and the second is the `.getSomeVal()` call? Then use a debugger and see which is giving you the null pointer exception.

Comment: @Jason That would be `producer.getProducer()` that is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mocked the `MyProducer` class, but you haven't provided a `when` for `producer.getProducer()`.

So, when the code calls `producer.getProducer()` it will return the default mock value, which is null.

You could try a couple of different approaches:

```
when(producer.getProducer()).thenReturn(producer);
```

I'm not sure if that will work - it might.

Otherwise, you may be able to write a local test class that implements/extends whatever getProducer() returns, which in turn returns the appropriate test value when the correct parameters are passed to `getSomeVal()`.

Comment: `MyInterceptor#intercept()` makes a call to `producer.getProducer().getSomeVal()`, and I thought enabling method chaining with `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` would cover that. Now as you claim, what do I need to add to make this work? I can't do `doReturn(/*some producer*/).when(producer).getProducer()` then the following line `when(producer.getProducer().getSomeVal(null, null)).thenReturn("SomeValue")` would complain about the wrong return type.

Comment: Even when I do `SomeObject fromProducer = doReturn(/*some producer*/).when(producer).getProducer()`, `when(fromProducer.getSomeVal(/*…*/).thenReturn("SomeValue")`, `fromProducer` is still null. I even tried `SomeObject fromProducer = doAnswer(new Answer() { /*…*/ }).when(producer).getProducer()` with the same outcome.

Comment: Edited to offer potential solutions.

Comment: A call to `producer.getProducer()` doesn't return `MyProducer`, but rather as I mentioned in the previous comment, it returns another object that I call `getSomeVal()` on. Regardless, I tried the suggested line and it was still throwing NPE. What I did was, in conjunction with yours, I ridded off `producer = Mockito.mock(MyProducer.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);` all together, as the application literally provides a static variable for `producer.getProducer()` in lower environments which I'm using to return in `thenReturn()` to use to call `getSomeVal()`, and that did the trick.